# Disable dropdown selection in newform aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, newform, classic-experience

I have below code which hide the dropdown but I want to disable it or greyout the selection

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(":input[title='SelectField']").children("option").hide();
// hide the lookup value which id is 3 and 4
  $(":input[title='SelectField']").children("option[value='3']").show();
  $(":input[title='SelectField']").children("option[value='4']").show();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You want to disable whole dropdown field or just few options in drop down? Is this a choice or lookup column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the whole dropdown field, you can use below:

**Using jQuery**:

```
$("select[title='SelectField']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

**Using JavaScript**:

```
document.querySelector("select[title='SelectField']").disabled = true
```

**OR**:

```
document.querySelector("select[title='Category']").disabled = 'disabled'
```

Where `SelectField` is the display name of your column.

**Output**:

[image]